# Values of $p$ such that $f(z)$ is an entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I feel I incorrectly tackle this problem:

> Determine for which values of $p\in \mathbb C$ there is an entire function $f(z)$ satisfying these conditons:
>   $$ |f'(z)| \leq |z| \quad \forall z \in \mathbb C $$ and $f(0)=p$,  $~f(1)=0$

My approach:
We notice that $f(z)$ must be entire, so we may write:
$$ f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_n z^n $$
Which converges on all of $\mathbb C$. We know how to  derive power series:
$$ f'(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty n c_n z^{n-1} $$
Which also converges again on all of $\mathbb C$ by an earlier lemma on the derivatives of (complex) power series. We conclude that $f'(z)$ is also entire, as it is analytic , hence holomorphic on all of $\mathbb C$. We observe the condition:
$$|f'(z)|\leq 1 \cdot |z^1| $$
implies by the generalised Liouville theorem that $f'(z)$ is a polynomial of at most degree $1$. We thus know for some $a_0, a_1 \in \mathbb C$:
$$  f'(z) = a_0 + a_1 z$$
We integrate with respect to $z$ and realise that:
$$ f(z) = C+ a_0 z + \frac{1}{2}a_1 z^2 $$
Now observe $f(0)=C=p$. The second condition only gives us that $f(1)=p+ a_0 + \frac{1}{2}a_1=0 \implies p=-a_0 - \frac{1}{2}a_1$

But it feels like I need more restrictions. I suppose it works for $\forall p \in \mathbb C$

I there an error in my reasoning here? I think this answer is rather weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f'(z)=a_0+a_1z$ and $|f'(z)|\leq |z|$, then in particular at $z=0$ you have $|a_0|\leq |0|$, so $a_0=0$. So, you in fact have $f'(z)=a_1 z$. Again, by the condition $|f'(z)|\leq |z|$, you get $|a_1|\leq 1$. I think those are the missing conditions.

Comment: I get $|p| \leq \frac{1}{2}$. Thank you.